# appscript that generate new google sheets document with specific range and sheets out of existing sheet when triggered

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to create a script that is able to take a specific range (maybe a named range) and a specific set of sheets out of an existing google sheet, and put them in a sheet that is newly cretated. That new file should be given a specific name and the actual date and time.

The problem is, that I'm completely new to coding and I have no clue where to begin.
Can someone help me with this please?

This is the current code:

```
    // @ts-nocheck
function example_createSpreadsheet() {
  const sourceSs_Id = 'SsIDhere';
  const destinationFolderId = 'FolderIDhere';

  const date1 = new Date(); //gets today's date
  const newSsName = 'Order from ' + justDate(date1) + ' at '  + justTime(date1); //takes your given Ss name and appends a formated today's date
  const newSs = SpreadsheetApp.create(newSsName);

  const newSs_Id = newSs.getId();

  var sheetsToCreate = ['Sheet1', 'Sheet2'];
  var namedRanges = ['Range1', 'Range2']; // in this case, we are assuming there is a named range for each sheet being created

  sheetsToCreate.forEach(
    function (sheet, index) {
      var newSheet = newSs
        .insertSheet()
        .setName(sheet);

      //remove excess rows and columns from new sheets
      //this example removes all but cell A1 in the sheet
      //when the coppied range is set, the needed rows and columns will automatically be added.
      var targetSheet = newSheet;
      var startRow = 1;
      var startCol = 1;
      var columnIndex = 3;
      example_removeRows(targetSheet, startRow);
      example_removeColumns(targetSheet, startCol);

      var namedRange_name = namedRanges[index]; //gets the range name by the corresponding index as forEach loops through the sheetsToCreate array
      var namedRange = SpreadsheetApp
        .openById(sourceSs_Id)
        .getRangeByName(namedRange_name)
        .getColumnWidth(columnIndex);
      var namedRange_values = namedRange.getValues();
      var namedRange_formulas = namedRange.getFormulas();
      var namedRange_BG = namedRange.getBackgrounds(); //get cell colors
      var namedRange_font = namedRange.getFontFamilies();
      var namedRange_fontcolor = namedRange.getFontColors();
      var namedRange_fontweights = namedRange.getFontWeights();
      var namedRange_fontsizes = namedRange.getFontSizes();
      var namedRange_HA = namedRange.getHorizontalAlignments();


      //assuming the coppied range will be set starting in cell A1, the row and column start values are set to 1
      var rangeStartRow = 1;
      var rangeStartCol = 1;
      var rangeRowCount = namedRange_values.length; //gets the row count of the range
      var rangeColCount = namedRange_values[0].length; //gets the column count of the first row in the range

      newSs.getSheetByName(sheet)
        .getRange(rangeStartRow, rangeStartCol, rangeRowCount, rangeColCount)
        .setValues(namedRange_values)
        .setFormulas(namedRange_formulas)
        .setBackgrounds(namedRange_BG)
        .setFontFamily(namedRange_font)
        .setFontColors(namedRange_fontcolor)
        .setFontWeights(namedRange_fontweights)
        .setFontSizes(namedRange_fontsizes)
        .setHorizontalAlignments(namedRange_HA)
        .setColumnWidth(columnIndex,widthInPixels);

    });

  const sheetToDelete = newSs.getSheetByName('Tabellenblatt1');
  newSs.deleteSheet(sheetToDelete);

  moveFile(newSs_Id, destinationFolderId);
}

function moveFile(newSs_Id, destinationFolderId) {
  const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(destinationFolderId);
  DriveApp.getFileById(newSs_Id).moveTo(destinationFolder);
}

function example_removeRows(targetSheet, startRow) {
  var maxRow = targetSheet.getMaxRows();
  if (maxRow > startRow && startRow > 0) {
    var rowCount = maxRow - startRow;
    targetSheet.deleteRows(startRow, rowCount);
  }
}

function example_removeColumns(targetSheet, startCol) {
  var maxCol = targetSheet.getMaxColumns();
  if (maxCol > startCol && startCol > 0) {
    var colCount = maxCol - startCol;
    targetSheet.deleteColumns(startCol, colCount);
  }
}
function justDate(dateItem) {
  var dateFormated = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(dateItem), 'Europe/Berlin', 'dd.MM.yyyy');
  //console.log(dateFormated);
  return dateFormated;
}
function justTime(dateItem) {
  var timeFormated = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(dateItem), 'Europe/Berlin', 'HH:mm ');
  //console.log(dateFormated);
  return timeFormated;
}
```

thanks
Claudia

I searched the internet in order to find snippets of code, that I then could copy into my script, but I fail to understand if the given code suits my needs.h

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example I believe has the components you are looking for. I threw in a function for moving the spreadsheet to a specific folder because when you create a new one like this it will show up in your root google drive folder and you will likely want it somewhere else. I tried to organize it to be as self explanatory as possible.

```
function testMyFunction() {
  const sourceSs_Id = 'PASTE_SOURCE_SPREADSHEET_ID_HERE';
  const sourceSs = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceSs_Id);
  const destinationFolderId = 'PASTE_FOLDER_ID_HERE';
  const newSsName = 'New Spreasheet Name';
  const newSs = SpreadsheetApp.create(newSsName);
  const newSs_Id = newSs.getId();

  var sheetsToCopy = ['Sheet2', 'Sheet3', 'Sheet4'];

  sheetsToCopy.forEach(
    function (sheet) {
      var sourceSheet = sourceSs.getSheetByName(sheet);
      var copiedSheet = sourceSheet.copyTo(newSs);
      copiedSheet.setName(sheet);
    });

  const namedRange_name = 'Range Name';
  const namedRange = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceSs_Id).getRangeByName(namedRange_name);
  const namedRange_values = namedRange.getValues();
  const namedRange_A1Notation = namedRange.getA1Notation();

  newSs.getSheetByName('Sheet Name')
    .getRange(namedRange_A1Notation)
    .setValues(namedRange_values);

  moveFile(newSs_Id, destinationFolderId);
}

function moveFile(newSs_Id, destinationFolderId) {
  const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(destinationFolderId);
  DriveApp.getFileById(newSs_Id).moveTo(destinationFolder);
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! It really does almost exactly what I need it to do!

1) The script copies all specified sheets as a whole, and ignores the given range, how do I fix that? 
2) And in the new spreadsheet, theres a sheet1 that get's created automatically, is there a way to prevent that?
3) I failed to include the current date in the name of the new file, how do I do that?

Thank you!

Comment: 1) ah, i didn't realize you wanted only a specific range from the target sheets copied. that would be a bit different. in that case, you would want to not actually copy the sheets to the new spreadsheet. You'd want to create the new Spreadsheet, then create new sheets in the new spreadsheet and name them to match your source sheets and then loop through them and copy the range from the source to the destination sheets.

Comment: 2) i don't believe you can prevent the Sheet1 from created, so you'd have to delete that sheet after the others are created.

Comment: 3) New file as in the spreadsheet name itself? If that is the case, instead of just setting the name, you want to start with the text name and then add the date to the name before setting it.

Comment: I'll try to throw together another script here when I get a few minutes to look at it again.

Answer (score 0):

I added this as a different answer because this is a slightly different solution after some clarification about what actually needs copied. Instead of copying the sheets from the source spreadsheet, only the ranges need to be copied.

I included a method to copy the cell background colors as well because that is often something people need to do in these cases, as well as a function for formatting the date so it can more easily be added to the the spreadsheet name.

```
function example_createSpreadsheet() {
  const sourceSs_Id = 'PASTE_SOURCE_SPREADSHEET_ID_HERE';
  const destinationFolderId = 'PASTE_FOLDER_ID_HERE';

  const dateItem = new Date(); //gets today's date
  const newSsName = 'New Spreasheet Name ' + justDate(dateItem); //takes your given Ss name and appends a formated today's date
  const newSs = SpreadsheetApp.create(newSsName);

  const newSs_Id = newSs.getId();

  var sheetsToCreate = ['Sheet2', 'Sheet3', 'Sheet4'];
  var namedRanges = ['NamedRange1', 'NamedRange2', 'NamedRange3']; // in this case, we are assuming there is a named range for each sheet being created

  sheetsToCreate.forEach(
    function (sheet, index) {
      var newSheet = newSs
        .insertSheet()
        .setName(sheet);

      //remove excess rows and columns from new sheets
      //this example removes all but cell A1 in the sheet
      //when the coppied range is set, the needed rows and columns will automatically be added.
      var targetSheet = newSheet;
      var startRow = 1;
      var startCol = 1;
      example_removeRows(targetSheet, startRow);
      example_removeColumns(targetSheet, startCol);

      var namedRange_name = namedRanges[index]; //gets the range name from the namedRanges array by the corresponding index as forEach loops through the sheetsToCreate array
      var namedRange = SpreadsheetApp
        .openById(sourceSs_Id)
        .getRangeByName(namedRange_name);
      var namedRange_values = namedRange.getValues();
      var namedRange_BG = namedRange.getBackgrounds(); //get cell colors

      //assuming the coppied range will be set starting in cell A1, the row and column start values are set to 1
      var rangeStartRow = 1;
      var rangeStartCol = 1;
      var rangeRowCount = namedRange_values.length; //gets the row count of the range
      var rangeColCount = namedRange_values[0].length; //gets the column count of the first row in the range

      newSs.getSheetByName(sheet)
        .getRange(rangeStartRow, rangeStartCol, rangeRowCount, rangeColCount)
        .setValues(namedRange_values)
        .setBackgrounds(namedRange_BG);
    });

  const sheetToDelete = newSs.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  newSs.deleteSheet(sheetToDelete);

  moveFile(newSs_Id, destinationFolderId);
}

function moveFile(newSs_Id, destinationFolderId) {
  const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(destinationFolderId);
  DriveApp.getFileById(newSs_Id).moveTo(destinationFolder);
}

function example_removeRows(targetSheet, startRow) {
  var maxRow = targetSheet.getMaxRows();
  if (maxRow > startRow && startRow > 0) {
    var rowCount = maxRow - startRow;
    targetSheet.deleteRows(startRow, rowCount);
  }
}

function example_removeColumns(targetSheet, startCol) {
  var maxCol = targetSheet.getMaxColumns();
  if (maxCol > startCol && startCol > 0) {
    var colCount = maxCol - startCol;
    targetSheet.deleteColumns(startCol, colCount);
  }
}

function justDate(dateItem) {
  var dateFormated = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(dateItem), 'America/Chicago', 'MM-dd-yyyy');
  //console.log(dateFormated);
  return dateFormated;
}
```

Comment: It does exactly what I needed it to do. Is there a way to copy the formatting and formulas too? It looks as if it only copys the value and the colors of the cells. Thank you!

Comment: I played a bit with variables and managed to copy fontsize, fontcolor, alignment etc.. , but I do not know how to get the column width and the formulas+values (not just one or the other, since I've been able to do both on it's own) into the new sheet

Comment: i believe you will have to get the formulas and cell values separately and handle them as separate arrays in the code. the column widths should be handled with .getColumnWidth(columnIndex) and .setColumnWidth(columnIndex,widthInPixels)

Comment: just to clarify if I got it right. when you say I need to handle values and formulas in separate arrays this is what you mean: `var namedRange_formulas = namedRange.getFormulas();
var namedRange_values = namedRange.getValues();` or did I get it wrong?
using `.getColumnWidth(columnIndex) 
.setColumnWidth(columnIndex,widthInPixels)` returns `ReferenceError: columnIndex is not defined`

Comment: yes that is correct, but you'll need to actually define the columIndex, so the script knows which column it is operating on. for example, if the column is the 5th column, the columnIndex would be 5. If you are looping through several columns then you'd need to iterate through the column indexes. "columnIndex" in that example is just a variable you need to define.

Comment: the script only copys one or the other, only formulas or values. the latter array overrides the first one. I defined a single row as the columnIndex for testing with `var columnIndex = 3;` under `sheetsToCreate.forEach`  added `.getColumnWith(columnIndex)` to the section where is says `var namedRange = SpreadsheetApp .openById(sourceSs_Id) .getRangeByName(namedRange_name)` and included `.setColumnWitdth(columnIndex,widthInPixels)` to `newSs.getSheetByName(sheet)` but now I get `getColumnWidth is not a function`

Comment: 1) i'm not sure exactly what you are referring to here. if you are trying to set a formula AND a value in the same cell, yeah, that doesn't even make sense. a formula will produce it's own value to display.  if you are trying to get a range with that covers both cells with values and other cells with formulas, you'll have to restructure you script to handle both separately. meaning, you'll have to cut up your original range so that you are only getting cells with formulas and setting those ranges specifically, then get the ranges with values and set those ranges specifically.

Comment: 2) i'm not sure what you mean with your explained use of getColumnWidth. to get a column width you have to specify the sheet and the column as in SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName).getColumnWidth(columnIndex) it will be the same with the setColumnWidth, these methods only work on individual columns in a sheet not on named ranges which span multiple columns and do not necessarily include all rows in a column. you'd have to loop through each column you want to get the width from and set each individual column in your target sheet.

Comment: it would helpful if you'd update your question with a sample of your current code as it is difficult to help when the intended result is not very clear.

Comment: Well in fact I want the script to take everything from a specific range of the source sheet, and put it in the new one, with formulas, values, format. from that point of view, the first attempt/script worked fine, except copying the whole sheet instead of only ranges.

I included the script as it is now in my question, if needed, I can provide a link to a sheet as the one I'm workin on too. thank you for your efforts!

Comment: It might be easier, in that case, to copy the whole sheet and then remove the stuff you don't want. In the new sheet by either clearing or removing the column/rows you don't want.

Comment: can I also do that with ranges (the deleting of unwanted content)? since the source file is changing constantly. If not I'd have to change the script everytime a row is added or deleted from the sheet

Comment: You should be able to define a named range, which changes dynamically as you add or remove rows/columns. The script, then, should be able to get the number of rows/columns from the range and have your script remove content or rows/columns that fall outside that range.